# SQL Server plus sign usage other than concat

Tags: python, sql-server, migration, concatenation

In SQL Server, are there possible instances where `+` may be used other than for string concatenation? I want to do a simple search and replace as part of my migration, but am worried that this may produce false positives where the original usage was not for concatenation.

I understand `+` can at least appear as a math operator as well, and right now I'm running this find and replace on any instance where `' +`, `+ '` etc are detected (this hopefully can make sure that only concat plus signs are replaced). Doing it this way would leave out lots of cases and I don't see an easy way to make this better. Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT 1 + 2;`? `SELECT GETDATE() + 1;`? `SELECT @VariableUnknownType + @OtherVariable;`? `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), 0x) + RTRIM(GETDATE());`? Basically, no, there is no magic shortcut to do this because explicit delimiters are not the only way you can concat strings, since not all strings are delimited string literals.

Comment: I understand that it's probably not easy to get all the possible usage all at once. I'm trying to see if this is as far as I can get with a simply search and replace safely. Even something like this will reduce manual workload by a lot in this migration. Thanks for pointing out these cases!

Comment: Maybe use TSqlParser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-150 and look for `TokenType.Plus`

Comment: There's also national character literals to consider when `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types are involved, e.g.: `select N'Unicode is wonderful!' + N'¡ʃnɟɹǝpuoʍ sı ǝpoɔıu∩'`

Answer (score 0):

At this point I'm looking at just using text processing to find any plus sign and ask for confirmation for every potential replacement to look through everything manually when `+ '` or `' +` is not found. Appreciate all the input in the comments.